# Android BottomNavigation avoid label getting truncated when selected

Tags: android, xml, label, bottomnavigationview, ellipse

One on my labels on the BottomNavigationView is too long and gets truncated with the 3 dots "..." when selected. Is there a way to avoid this behavior? (See images)
I need to show the whole text.

[Item Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1pn8.jpg)

[Item Not Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pquHE.jpg)

Here is my xml code for BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/sabbia_aiba"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```